# Rails: How do I write a spec for a route that does a redirect?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, rspec, omniauth

I am using Omniauth in my Rails project, and I'd like to hide "/auth/facebook" behind a "/login" route.

In fact, I wrote a route:

```
match "/login", :to => redirect("/auth/facebook"), :as => :login
```

and this actually works, i.e. a link to `login_path` will redirect to `/auth/facebook`.

However, how can I write a (RSpec) spec to test this route (specifically, the redirect)?

Do note that `/login` is not an actual action nor method defined in the application.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Example Rspec Routes](https://cbabhusal.wordpress.com/2015/12/15/rails-rspec-examples-of-routing-specs/#more-1623)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because you didn't provide any detail about your environment, the following example assumes you are using rspec 2.x and rspec-rails, with Rails 3.

```
# rspec/requests/redirects_spec.rb
describe "Redirects" do
  describe "GET login" do
    before(:each) do
      get "/login"
    end

    it "redirects to /auth/facebook" do
      response.code.should == "302"
      response.location.should == "/auth/facebook"
    end
  end
end
```

Read the Request Specs section of [rspec-rails](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails) for more details.

Comment: This works! Thanks! The key is in defining this spec in #spec/requests/redirects as you have mentioned. Previously, I was doing it in either ApplicationControllerSpec (which resulted in the error that action "/login" cannot be found in the ApplicationController), or in one of the spec/routing specs with "*.should route_to blah" (which complained that the route does not exist).

Comment: And yes, I am using rspec(-rails) 2.x with Rails 3.

Comment: Just another note that the file should be named redirects_spec.rb, so that the default Rake task will pick it up when you just do 'Rake' on the command line.

Comment: Isn't it bad practice to have multiple assertions?

Comment: You can write one assertion per block if you prefer. But in this case I believe it's fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use:

```
get "/login"
response.should redirect_to(path)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Rack::Test](https://github.com/brynary/rack-test) and check the url and the http status code

```
get "/login"
last_response.status.should == 302
last_response.headers["Location"].should == "/auth/facebook"
```